# How to identify the screen from where navigated from. DrawerNavigation or StackNavigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a scenario, where I am using **screen1** from **footer tab(Stack)** as well as from left menu(drawer). I have added delay of 300ms which is fine for drawernavigation, because screen waits until drawer closes, but in footer tab the same delay was applied and which I need to override.

Is there any way to identify which navigation was used to navigate under **transitionConfig** This is the piece of code which I try to modify but that doesn't solve

```
navigationOptions: {
  transitionConfig: (toTransitionProps, fromTransitionProps) => {
    const isBack = fromTransitionProps.navigation.state.index >= toTransitionProps.navigation.state.index;
    const routeName = isBack ? fromTransitionProps.scene.route.routeName : toTransitionProps.scene.route.routeName;

    // This check is only for the case where the transitionConfig is specified globally per navigator basis
    // If the config is specified per screen basis, then `routeName` will always refer to the current screen
    if (routeName === 'Search') {
      return {
        transitionSpec: { duration: isBack ? 150 : 200 },
        screenInterpolator: CardStackStyleInterpolator.forFade(props),
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Referred from [Github Issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/10)

Answer (score 0):

From [the code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/flow/react-navigation.js#L673) I can see that the navigation state can be accessed. This means you can pass a parameter when calling `navigate` (or `push`) to specify which element invoked the navigation, which you can then read in the navigation state.

```
toTransitionProps.navigation.getParam('invokedBy',/*default value*/)
```